# iOS notification block if app closed

Tags: ios, swift2, apple-push-notifications

I have set up notifications and all ok. However notifications are still showing even when the app is closed. I only want the user to get a notification if the app is in background.

The UIApplicationState only seems to deal with Active, Inactive and Background and Inactive seems to apply to an interruption to the running app.

What is the procedure for preventing notifications if the app is closed?

Thanks.

EDIT: As shallowThought pointed out, I am referring here to Push Notifications but didn't consider the confusion with local notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Local Notifications:

You can not guarantee this. You can remove all `NSNotifications` in`applicationWillTerminate`. It will not work in state `suspended` though.

> If your app is running (either in the foreground or background) at termination time, the system calls your app delegate’s applicationWillTerminate: method so that you can perform any required cleanup. You can use this method to save user data or app state information that you would use to restore your app to its current state on a subsequent launch. Your method has approximately 5 seconds to perform any tasks and return. If it does not return in time, the app is killed and removed from memory.
>
> Important: The applicationWillTerminate: method is not called if your app is currently suspended.

---

For Push Notifications:

You can send (push) a silent notifications. This wakes up your app. Assuming you track the lifecycle state of your app, you can schedule a local notification in case you want to inform the user.

Comment: Many thanks - is that the unregisterForRemoteNotifications call?

Comment: I thoght you are referring to local notifications. Updated answer.